# How can I use the Task.Run(Func<Task> f) method signature?

Tags: c#

To use this method :

```
public static Task Run(Action action)
```

I just write :

```
void MyMethod(){ //do something }
Task t = Task.Run(new Action(MyMethod));
```

However I do not understand how to use the following overload

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task> f)
```

The msdn mentions that the returned task is "a proxy for the task
returned by f" which is even more confusing to me. What is meant by proxy and how would I call this method?

Answer (score 7):

`Func<Task>` is simply a function that *returns* a task.  *That* task is then executed.

So `Task Run( Func<Task> f )` returns a `Task`, whose job is to run another `Task` (the one created by `f`).  *That's* what's meant by a "proxy".

However, read the Note on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis added):

> The `Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>>)` method is used by language compilers to support the `async` and `await` keywords. ***It is not intended to be called directly from user code***.

Comment: It looks like the note disappeared

Answer (score 1):

[`Func<T>`](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=func%3CT%3E) is a generic delegate - here's its full signature:

```
public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>()
```

As you can see, it represents a function that takes no parameters, and returns an instance of type `TResult`. In the case of `Func<Task>`, `TResult` is `Task`.

What this means, is that you can do this:

```
public Task MyAsyncMethod() { ... }

Task.Run(MyAsyncMethod);
```

This converts your method `MyAsyncMethod` into a delegate of type `Func<Task>` and passes it to `Task.Run`. It's syntactic sugar for `Task.Run( new Func<Task>(MyAsyncMethod) );`

> The msdn mentions that the returned task is "a proxy for the task returned by f" which is even more confusing to me (what is meant by proxy ?)

What this means is that `Task.Run` will simply wrap the task returned by `MyAsyncMethod` is another `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

That signature allows you to provide a method that returns a Task, when you run `Task.Run`. That is because the last generic argument of a `Func<T>` is the return value given back by the delegate you provide. Meaning:

```
public Func<bool> IsValid = this.ValidateUser;
public bool ValidateUser() { return someUser.IsAuthenticated; }
```

or even just

```
public Func<bool> IsValidUser = this.User.IsAuthenticated;
```

Then you can use the delegate as you would any other method, and the delegate will return a bool.

```
public void Foo()
{
    if (!IsValidUser()) throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid user");
}
```

You can use parameters that are passed in to the delegate, by providing additional generic types other than the return value.

```
Func<int, bool> IsUserAgeValid = (age) => return age > 18;

// Invoke the age check
bool result = this.IsUserAgeValid(17);
```

The thing to remember is that the last generic is always the return type in a Func. If only one generic is provided, then there is no parameters, only a return type.

A `Func<Task>` allows you to use an `awaitable` method in your `Task.Run` call.
This also means that you can `await` from within the anonymous delegate you provide.

```
public Task Foo()
{
    /* .. do stuff */
}

public void Bar()
{
    Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            await Foo();
            /* do additional work */
        });
}
```

and if you don't need to await the call to `Foo()`, you can just give `Task.Run` the `Foo` method.

```
Task.Run(Foo);
```

If you find yourself wanting to await the awaitable method given to `Task.Run` as shown above, it is probably better that you use `ContinueWith`.

```
public void Bar()
{
    Task.Run(Foo).ContinueWith(foosTaskResult => 
    {    
        /* Do stuff */
    });
}
```

The MSDN documentation saying the the Task returned is a *proxy* for the Task of *f*, basically means that

```
Task returnedTask = Task.Run(Foo);
```

will set `returnedTask` to be the Task that was returned by the call to the awaitable `Foo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

a `Func<T>` refers to a method which returns `T`, which in this case is a `Task`. Thus, to make `MyMethod` compatible with this particular overload, you would write

```
Task MyMethod() {...}
```

Which also means you could make `MyMethod` and `async` method, thus

```
async Task MyMethod() {...}
```

When referring to a "proxy" this means that the `Task` returned by `Task.Run` isn't actually the task returned by `MyMethod`, but instead wraps it.