# public static Task Run(Func<Task> function);

Tags: c#

Can anybody provide any examples/code snippet to use below method.

`public static Task Run(Func<Task> function);`

I am trying to understand how to use the above overloaded method but I did not find any code in web.

As far as I understand this method takes `func delegate` as input parameter which should return a Task so please provide me some code snippet.

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918061/passing-a-task-as-parameter

Comment: @VinodMG Please clarify if you are talking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use the Task.Run(Func<Task> f) method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400089/how-can-i-use-the-task-runfunctask-f-method-signature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This overload is often used to offload task to a thread pool thread.
Suppose you wrote this method inside console app:

```
    private static async Task DoSomeHeavyInitializationAsync()
    {
        // some heavy calculations;

        // some async I/O (e.q. reading from database, file, etc);
        await SomeMethodAsync(...);

        // again some heavy calculations, async I/O, etc...
    }
```

Now you want to call it from `Program.Main`, and keep `Main` responsive: if user don't want to wait app being initialized, he can press [enter] and terminate the app.

So, you need to offload task to be sure, that its code won't run on main thread. `Task Run(Func<Task>)` helps you:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(DoSomeHeavyInitializationAsync);

        // do something else...

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```